# What programming language could Iron Man's Jarvis be programmed in?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

My question is simple - assuming today's technologies and possibilities, what could be the best setup to build such intelligent system? Could today's intelligent systems such as Siri, or Google's voice controlled search be the ancestors for a complex AI system, or are there other, less known projects, that are trying to build an intelligent system?

What would be the main goals for creating such system (this could help in choosing the technologies)? I came up quickly with these basics:

- voice communication (with some kind of personality, capable of politeness and sarcasm) - already accomplished with e.g. Siri
- remote communication (e.g. with Iron Man suit)
- a central server(s) - is this known, where was Iron Man's Jarivs server? (Latest Avengers movie could point to Stark's skyscraper)
- ability to control other devices connected to Jarvis remotely (e.g. energy transportation between suit repulsors, or some things in Stark's buildings - these are actually just basic interfaces)
- ability to identify dangerous decisions of a user and warn him/her (I'm not an AI problematic expert, but I guess this is something common AI programmers deal with)

Others..? I only know Iron Man from the movies, are there any indices in the comic books about Jarvis technologies?

I'm sorry if this question is not very constructive, but once I read a discussion about how could Skynet be programmed in NodeJS, and this started bugging my mind :)

Comment: Programs can usually be written in a wide variety of languages, and compiled into machine code or other languages even.  Thus this question is meaning less.

Comment: Worth pointing out that Jarvis is copied into the suit, and there are likely multiple Jarvis 'servers' - there's likely to be one in the tower, one in his home, one in each suit, etc.

Comment: I would not consider Siri, or any other voice controlled application, an intelligent system. They're just applications.

Comment: Jeff, is it somewhere stated, that Jarvis in the suit is a copy of Jarvis in the tower? I would say that more logical is if those were just client applications communicating with the server(s).

Comment: Teo - Yes.  In the first movie, when Tony builds the Mark II suit, Jarvis uploads into it.  There's a bit of dialogue there about it, just before the first flight test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The programming language I think is not **the most** important part, yes, there are some of them that have some helpfull constructs when it comes to working with AI, but in theory, you could use almost any language (at least of the widely used ones, like C, C++, JAVA, Ruby, Python, etc, etc).

And relating to the other part of your question, I would relate the Movie Jarvis to [IBM's Watson](http://www-03.ibm.com/innovation/us/watson/) more than I would realte it to a Siri or a Google Voice Search... I think Watson could be a perfect example of a "parent" for something like Jarvis.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about Watson, that's a great example! (and I'm a former IBMer, shame on me)

Comment: And, like any complex system, different portions are probably coded in different languages.

Comment: I'd add a bit about any "turing complete" language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness